# binarySearch vs in, Unexpected Results (Python)

Tags: python, time-complexity, binary-search

I am trying to compare the complexity of in and binarySearch in python2. Expecting O(1) for in and O(logn) for binarySearch. However, the results are unexpected. Are programs timed incorrectly or there is another mistake?

Here is the code:

```
import time

x = [x for x in range(1000000)]
def Time_in(alist,item):
    t1  = time.time()
    found = item in alist
    t2 = time.time()
    timer = t2 - t1  
    return found, timer

def Time_binarySearch(alist, item):
    first = 0
    last = len(alist)-1
    found = False 
    t1 = time.time()
    while first<=last and not found:
        midpoint = (first + last)//2
        if alist[midpoint] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            if item < alist[midpoint]:
                last = midpoint-1
            else:
                first = midpoint+1
    t2 = time.time()
    timer = t2 - t1
    return found, timer

print "binarySearch: ", Time_binarySearch(x, 600000)
print "in: ", Time_in(x, 600000)
```

The results are:

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows that `binary_search` is too fast to measure, and `in` is pretty fast, but measurable, thus slower. Seems exactly what you expect, doesn't it?

Comment: I think in O(1) should be faster than binarySearch O(logn).

Comment: If you use `ipython` (highly recommended for exploratory work like this), use smth like `%time xx_find(alist, item)` which will run enough iterations to give a sensible result.

Comment: Oh, `x in list(...)` is O(N), and `x in as set(...)` is O(1), that's where you went astray...

Comment: It is O(n) for in. (Dictionaries/sets can claim O(1) but are more realistically O (log n))

Comment: In standard Python you should use the `timeit` module for timing tests rather than `time.time()`.

Answer (score 3):

The binary search is going so fast that when you try to print the time it took, it just prints `0.0`. Whereas using `in` takes long enough that you see the very small fraction of a second it took.

The reason that `in` does take longer is because this is a list, not a `set` or similar data structure; whereas with a set, membership testing is somewhere between O(1) and O(logn), in a list, every element has to be checked in order until there's a match, or the list is exhausted.

Here's some benchmarking code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import bisect
import timeit


def binarysearch(alist, item):
    first = 0
    last = len(alist) - 1
    found = False
    while first <= last and not found:
        midpoint = (first + last) // 2
        if alist[midpoint] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            if item < alist[midpoint]:
                last = midpoint - 1
            else:
                first = midpoint + 1
    return found


def bisect_index(alist, item):
    idx = bisect.bisect_left(alist, item)
    if idx != len(alist) and alist[idx] == item:
        found = True
    else:
        found = False
    return found


time_tests = [
    ('    600 in list(range(1000))',
     '600 in alist',
     'alist = list(range(1000))'),
    ('    600 in list(range(10000000))',
     '600 in alist',
     'alist = list(range(10000000))'),

    ('    600 in set(range(1000))',
     '600 in aset',
     'aset = set(range(1000))'),
    ('6000000 in set(range(10000000))',
     '6000000 in aset',
     'aset = set(range(10000000))'),

    ('binarysearch(list(range(1000)), 600)',
     'binarysearch(alist, 600)',
     'from __main__ import binarysearch; alist = list(range(1000))'),
    ('binarysearch(list(range(10000000)), 6000000)',
     'binarysearch(alist, 6000000)',
     'from __main__ import binarysearch; alist = list(range(10000000))'),

    ('bisect_index(list(range(1000)), 600)',
     'bisect_index(alist, 600)',
     'from __main__ import bisect_index; alist = list(range(1000))'),
    ('bisect_index(list(range(10000000)), 6000000)',
     'bisect_index(alist, 6000000)',
     'from __main__ import bisect_index; alist = list(range(10000000))'),
    ]

for display, statement, setup in time_tests:
    result = timeit.timeit(statement, setup, number=1000000)
    print('{0:<45}{1}'.format(display, result))
```

And the results:

```
# Python 2.7

    600 in list(range(1000))                 5.29039907455
    600 in list(range(10000000))             5.22499394417
    600 in set(range(1000))                  0.0402979850769
6000000 in set(range(10000000))              0.0390179157257
binarysearch(list(range(1000)), 600)         0.961972951889
binarysearch(list(range(10000000)), 6000000) 3.014950037
bisect_index(list(range(1000)), 600)         0.421462059021
bisect_index(list(range(10000000)), 6000000) 0.634694814682

# Python 3.4

    600 in list(range(1000))                 8.578510413994081
    600 in list(range(10000000))             8.578105041990057
    600 in set(range(1000))                  0.04088461003266275
6000000 in set(range(10000000))              0.043901249999180436
binarysearch(list(range(1000)), 600)         1.6799193460028619
binarysearch(list(range(10000000)), 6000000) 6.099467994994484
bisect_index(list(range(1000)), 600)         0.5168328559957445
bisect_index(list(range(10000000)), 6000000) 0.7694612839259207

# PyPy 2.6.0 (Python 2.7.9)

    600 in list(range(1000))                 0.122292041779
    600 in list(range(10000000))             0.00196599960327
    600 in set(range(1000))                  0.101480007172
6000000 in set(range(10000000))              0.00759720802307
binarysearch(list(range(1000)), 600)         0.242530822754
binarysearch(list(range(10000000)), 6000000) 0.189949035645
bisect_index(list(range(1000)), 600)         0.132127046585
bisect_index(list(range(10000000)), 6000000) 0.197204828262
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you expect O(1) when testing if an element is contained in a list?
If you don't know anything about the list (like that it is sorted as in your example) then you have to go through each element and compare it.

So you get O(N).

Python lists cannot assume anything about what you store in them, so they have to use a naive implementation for `list.__contains__`.
If you want a faster test, then you can try to use a dictionary or set.

Answer (score 0):

Here are time complexities of all methods for lists in python:
[image]

So as it can be seen x in s is O(n), which is significantly slower than binarySearch O(logn).